# setup.py install not working for django-visits

Tags: django, python-2.7, setuptools

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, the process seemed pretty straight forward:

I had to fix something for the django-visits module and so I forked this:

https://bitbucket.org/jespino/django-visits

Did the fix.

Then in the source folder tried to do a:

`python setup.py install`

on my mac os x.  First it gives an error:

```
Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Searching for setuptools==21.2.1
Best match: setuptools 21.2.1
Adding setuptools 21.2.1 to easy-install.pth file
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools.pth'
```

So I did:

`sudo python setup.py install`

and I got this output:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to django_visits.egg-info/requires.txt
writing django_visits.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to django_visits.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to django_visits.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'django_visits.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'django_visits.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg
copying build/lib/.DS_Store -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
copying build/lib/visits/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
copying build/lib/visits/admin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
copying build/lib/visits/context_processors.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
copying build/lib/visits/middleware.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/migrations
copying build/lib/visits/migrations/0001_initial.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/migrations
copying build/lib/visits/migrations/0002_auto__chg_field_visit_uri.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/migrations
copying build/lib/visits/migrations/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/migrations
copying build/lib/visits/models.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
copying build/lib/visits/settings.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/templatetags
copying build/lib/visits/templatetags/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/templatetags
copying build/lib/visits/templatetags/visits_tags.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/templatetags
copying build/lib/visits/tests.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
copying build/lib/visits/utils.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/admin.py to admin.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/context_processors.py to context_processors.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/middleware.py to middleware.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/migrations/0001_initial.py to 0001_initial.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/migrations/0002_auto__chg_field_visit_uri.py to 0002_auto__chg_field_visit_uri.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/migrations/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/models.py to models.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/settings.py to settings.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/templatetags/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/templatetags/visits_tags.py to visits_tags.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/tests.py to tests.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/visits/utils.py to utils.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying django_visits.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying django_visits.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying django_visits.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying django_visits.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying django_visits.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/django_visits-0.1.6-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing django_visits-0.1.6-py2.7.egg
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_visits-0.1.6-py2.7.egg
Copying django_visits-0.1.6-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
django-visits 0.1.6 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_visits-0.1.6-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for django-visits==0.1.6
Searching for distribute==0.7.3
Best match: distribute 0.7.3
Adding distribute 0.7.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Searching for setuptools==21.2.1
Best match: setuptools 21.2.1
Adding setuptools 21.2.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing easy_install-3.5 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for django-visits==0.1.6
```

Looks like it worked, I runserver on my django app that is using this and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 170, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 98, in load_disk
    for name in os.listdir(directory):
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_visits-0.1.6-py2.7.egg/visits/migrations'
```

I look into that site-packages folder and sure enough the .egg is a file not a folder?  Yet in the source the build and lib folders look right.

So I am perplexed with such a simple command of python setup.py install how this is going so awry?

(I should note that I can run python setup.py build) and copy the egg folder it creates to the site-packages folder.  I get a different error though because then it doesn't think the code is there (and no model exists from the project).  Someone mentioned migrations in the comments but I am not sure how that matters?  I have some un ran migrations in my project but they are ones I am specifically witholding that I do not want to run (independent of this)

Comment: please try to makemigrations for the first time. it is required

Comment: I think it is because your forked app is not installed correctly. How did you add your forked app to your project?

Comment: I am not sure how the migrations matter in this instance if the setup.py is not installing it to the right spots.   Also, I just forked the code in bitbucket, and then did a hg clone on it to get it down to my local machine.  where I made the change to the model and then tried to do the python setup.py install